# I want to Search places from particular city using Google API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to search the places in `UITextField`, I am using `GMSAutocompleteViewController` when I click on the `UITextField` it is navigating to other view controller but I want search list in the same view and I want the places from particular city, now it is showing places from all over the world you can see in screen shots. This is my present code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
    acController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];

    return true;
}


- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    // Do something with the selected place.
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
    NSLog(@"lat and log%f", place.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"lang %f", place.coordinate.longitude);

    _searchTextField.text = place.name;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    NSLog(@"error: %ld", (long)[error code]);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

// User canceled the operation.
- (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"Autocomplete was cancelled.");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[Screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMp1.png)

[Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnkb5.png)

Answer (score 0):

GMSAutoCompleteViewController is responsible for handling user input along with getting autocomplete results and displaying them.

To have a customized ViewController, you will need to do all the above process by yourself. 
Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically) to programmatically get the autocomplete results from Google API's.
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The best way to restrict search in specific area is to create a path and check if requested lat,lng are inside it or not. Also this approach can be used for autocomplete API, once user has selected some result from row we can get its lat,lng and check if these are in our city/country path. 
[image]
Below is some code to understand better. e.g i want user to restrict in UAE. 
First get the boundary coordinates of UAE and save these in list. Below code can be used to get boundary coordinates.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)  {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    if(isDrawing == true)
    {
        self.viewMap.clear()
        path.add(coordinate)
        let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline.strokeColor = .blue
        polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
        polyline.map = self.viewMap
        points.add(String(format:"%f,%f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude))
    }

}
```

Once you have marked whole boundary points then these can be save like this

```
let strPoints:String! = points.componentsJoined(by: "|")
print(strPoints)
```

you will see in console something like this

```
"26.050692,56.086607|26.117957,54.749640|25.901079,53.631803|24.620641,51.447101|24.274502,51.575709|22.926947,52.593388|22.777518,53.985706|22.645116,55.149715|22.701870,55.227998|23.016172,55.222406|23.375945,55.401338|23.698908,55.574679|23.842193,55.524355|23.949552,55.501988|24.046609,55.787162|24.061928,56.010827|24.184407,55.982869|24.220108,55.966095|24.204809,55.837486|24.255799,55.764795|24.403556,55.848670|24.540967,55.775979|24.637573,55.809528|24.759496,55.837486|24.916802,55.820711|24.967504,55.871037|24.987778,55.960503|24.967504,56.061152|24.876227,56.072336|24.886372,55.977278|24.754418,56.066744|24.769651,56.206535|24.835637,56.234493|24.932015,56.351918|24.972573,56.379876|25.256102,57.028506|25.896649,56.732150|26.368532,56.687416|26.488706,56.268043|26.348491,55.943728|26.388570,55.233589|26.413612,54.322151|26.183019,54.350110|26.107726,54.355701|26.027361,54.361293"
```

Copy it and save in your code

```
    path = GMSMutablePath()
    points = NSMutableArray()
    let pointsStr:String! = "26.050692,56.086607|26.117957,54.749640|25.901079,53.631803|24.620641,51.447101|24.274502,51.575709|22.926947,52.593388|22.777518,53.985706|22.645116,55.149715|22.701870,55.227998|23.016172,55.222406|23.375945,55.401338|23.698908,55.574679|23.842193,55.524355|23.949552,55.501988|24.046609,55.787162|24.061928,56.010827|24.184407,55.982869|24.220108,55.966095|24.204809,55.837486|24.255799,55.764795|24.403556,55.848670|24.540967,55.775979|24.637573,55.809528|24.759496,55.837486|24.916802,55.820711|24.967504,55.871037|24.987778,55.960503|24.967504,56.061152|24.876227,56.072336|24.886372,55.977278|24.754418,56.066744|24.769651,56.206535|24.835637,56.234493|24.932015,56.351918|24.972573,56.379876|25.256102,57.028506|25.896649,56.732150|26.368532,56.687416|26.488706,56.268043|26.348491,55.943728|26.388570,55.233589|26.413612,54.322151|26.183019,54.350110|26.107726,54.355701|26.027361,54.361293"
    let pp = pointsStr.components(separatedBy: "|")
    for item in pp {

        let coor = item.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let lat:Double! = (coor[0] as AnyObject).doubleValue
        let lng:Double! = (coor[1] as AnyObject).doubleValue
        let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D! = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        path.add(coordinate)
    }

    if(self.isCoordinateInside(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: selectedPlace.lat, longitude: selectedPlace.lng)) == true)
    {

    }



func isCoordinateInside(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)->Bool{

    if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinate, path, true) == true)
    {

        print("locationPoint is in polygonPath.")
        return true

    }
    else
    {

        print("locationPoint is NOT in polygonPath.")
        return false

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to["Google Places API"](http://%22Google%20Places%20API%22)  and get your API key.

Then, Use below mention code to create request

```
 var url: String = 
 "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=\
 (lat),\(lang)&radius=100&sensor=true&key=\(GOOGLE_API_KEY)"

 var googleRequestURL = URL(string: url)

 var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: googleRequestURL!)

 request.httpMethod = "GET"

 request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-
 Type")
```

Change the radius as per your need. please enter your current location in lats and longs.